# Why Passport.js facebook token strategy doesnt call profile fetching?

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js

I have such facebook token strategy

```
passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
    profileURL: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,username,name,picture,friends,email'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      User.findOne({ 'facebook.id': profile.id }, {facebook:0,twitter:0, google:0}, function (err, user) {

        //console.log('profile._json', profile._json)
        if (err) { return done(err) }
        if (!user) {
          user = new User({
            name: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            username: profile.username,
            provider: 'facebook',
            facebook: profile._json,
            friends: profile.friends,
            profilePicture: profile.profilePicture
          })
          user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
              console.log('saved:',user)
            return done(err, user)
          })
        }
        else {
          return done(err, user)
        }
      })
  }
));
```

And route

```
  app.get('/auth/facebook/token', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('auth by fb token');
    passport.authenticate('facebook-token', { scope: [ 'email', 'user_about_me', 'user_birthday', 'user_friends', 'user_interests'] }, function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      if (!user) { return res.json({"error":true, "messages": info.message }) }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err)

                res.json({"result":user});

       })
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

The thing is that on my local machine it seems like .profilePicture field is populated correctly because this code is called

```
FacebookTokenStrategy.prototype.userProfile = function(accessToken, done)
```

which has this code:
this._oauth2.getProtectedResource(url, accessToken, function (err, body, res) {
    if (err) { return done(new InternalOAuthError('failed to fetch user profile', err)); }

```
try {
  var json = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log('FB JSON:',json);
  var profile = { provider: 'facebook' };
  profile.id = json.id;
  profile.username = json.username;
  profile.displayName = json.name;
  profile.name = { familyName: json.last_name,
                   givenName: json.first_name,
                   middleName: json.middle_name };
  profile.gender = json.gender;
  profile.profileUrl = json.link;
  profile.emails = [{ value: json.email }];
  profile.friends = json.friends.data;
  console.log('pict:',json.picture)
        console.log('pict:',json.picture.data)
              console.log('pict:',json.picture.data.url)
  profile.profilePicture = json.picture.data.url;

  profile._raw = body;
  profile._json = json;

  done(null, profile);
} catch(e) {
  done(e);
}
```

});

But on production it simply doesnt call this method and profilePicture with friends are undefined

So here is the result I get on local machine and production:

```
{
-result: {
_id: "531c4db62572a00800000008"
__v: 0
authToken: ""
salt: ""
hashed_password: ""
provider: "facebook"
username: "arthur.k "
email: ""
name: "Arthur K "
friends: [ ]
}
}




{
-result: {
profilePicture: https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/t5/275845_100000386000031_189566_q.jpg
_id: "531c43798f3961660409e693"
__v: 0
authToken: ""
salt: ""
hashed_password: ""
provider: "facebook"
username: "arthur.k "
email: ""
name: "Arthur K "
+friends: [ … ]
}
}
```

I tried debugging passport.js but it seems that the solution is more obvious and less painful :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your configuration the same in development and production as far as  app id, secret id, permissions, etc? Why do you think it isn't running code in production?

Comment: Yes, config for passport is the same, I see that it is not running cause I've filled all these "fetching" functions with console.logs :)